# Is update/select of a single column in a single row atomic and safe in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to use the following statement to update a column of a single row:

```
UPDATE Test SET Column1 = Column1 & ~2 WHERE Id = 1
```

The above seems to work. Is this safe in SQL Server? I remember reading about possible deadlocks when using similar statments in a non-SQL Server DBMS (I think it was related to PostgreSQL).

Example of a table and corresponding stored procs:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, Column1 int NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY (Id ASC))
GO
INSERT INTO Test (Column1) Values(255) 
GO
-- this will always affect a single row only
UPDATE Test SET Column1 = Column1 & ~2 WHERE Id = 1
```

Comment: Note that an `update` and `select` is _not_ atomic unless you wrap it in a suitable transaction and everyone plays nicely. You could use an [`output` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to capture both the _before_ and _after_ values in the `update` statement, as an atomic operation, for later use, e.g, in a `select`.

Comment: @HABO I'm aware of a solution with a transaction as well as output clause. However, the syntax "SET Column1 = Column1 & ~2" statement is very attractive and this is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the table structure you have shown both the `UPDATE` and the `SELECT` are standalone transactions and can use clustered index seeks to do their work without needing to read unnecessary rows and take unnecessary locks so I would not be particularly concerned about deadlocks with this procedure.

I would be more concerned about the fact that you don't have the `UPDATE` and `SELECT` inside the same transaction. So the `X` lock on the row will be released as soon as the update statement finishes and it will be possible for another transaction to change the column value (or even delete the whole row) before the `SELECT` is executed.

If you execute both statements inside the same transaction then I still wouldn't be concerned about deadlock potential as the exclusive lock is taken first (it would be a different matter if the `SELECT` happened before the `UPDATE`)

You can also address the concurrency issue by getting rid of the `SELECT` entirely and using the `OUTPUT` clause to return the post-update value to the client.

```
UPDATE Test SET Column1 = Column1 & ~2 
OUTPUT INSERTED.Column1
WHERE Id = 1
```

Comment: It was my mistake to include the SELECT statement (I've already removed it) after the update in the example. My main concern is the UPDATE statement only. Just to clarify: you do not see any chance of deadlocs with the following: UPDATE Test SET Column1 = Column1 & ~2 WHERE Id = 1?

Comment: What exactly is your deadlock concern here? A deadlock requires at least 2 processes. Which may or may not both be executing the same SQL. There's nothing special about the statement you have shown which means that deadlocks would be a particular concern, I doubt that it would be possible to engineer a deadlock involving that statement and table structure even if you were specifically trying to do so.

Comment: I remember reading an article about PostgreSQL where the author clearly demonstrated a possible deadlock with the UPDATE statement which modified column value taking into account current value of the same column. For example, instead of a simple statement like 'UPDATE SET Column1 = <value>' the statment was 'UPDATE SET Column1 = Column1 + <value>'. The second statement implies a reading Column1 first and then updating it. Supposedly in PostgreSQL executing the second statement in multiple concurrent sessions was causing deadlocks.

Comment: @gordieb - definitely not an issue with SQL Server. It will take `U` locks whilst reading the rows for an `UPDATE` and convert them to `X` locks when doing the update. `U` and `X` locks are not compatible either with themselves or the other lock type so only one process can take any of those locks out on a row and all other processes trying to update that row will just have to wait

Comment: You might get this issue if both processes took `S` locks on the row and then tried to upgrade them to `X` locks but that is not how things work in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "is it safe"?

Your `id` is a unique identifier for each row.  I would strongly encourage you to declare it as a `primary key`.  But you should have an index on the column.

Without an index, you do have a potential issue with performance (and deadlocks) because SQL Server has to scan the entire table.  But with the appropriate `primary key` declaration (or another index), then you are only updating a single row in a single table.  If you have no triggers on the table, then there is not much going on that can interfere with other transactions.

Comment: By "is it safe?" i meant to ask if the update statement could cause any deadlocks.  Btw, in the actual table Id column is a primary key. I'll try to update the example accordingly.